# SwiftUI: how to remove spacing around Text()?

Tags: swiftui

As example I have 3 properties:

```
var path1FilePath:String = "Src/"
var path2FileName: String = "filename"
var path3Extension: String = ".jpg"
```

I need to display them with the following way:

```
HStack {
    Text(status.path1FilePath)
    Text(status.path2FileName).bold()
    Text(status.path3Extension)
}
```

problem is spacing between `Text()` views. How to remove them?

> [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SwiftUI allows us to combine strings together like `Text("Hello ") + Text("World!")`, so you can do the same here:

```
Text(path1FilePath)
    + Text(path2FileName)
    + Text(path3Extension)
```

[image: SwiftUI Text combination]

Alternatively, if you still want or need to use an `HStack`, just use `HStack(spacing: 0)` and you'll get the same result.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 ways:

Solution 1:

```
Text(path1FilePath)
    + Text(path2FileName)
    + Text(path3Extension)
```

but in this way you cannot apply modifiers =(

---

Solution 2:

```
HStack (spacing: 0) {
    Text(path1FilePath)
    Text(path2FileName)
        .bold()
    Text(path3Extension)
}
.someTextModifier()
```